# JQuery on wordpress not working consistently

Tags: jquery, wordpress, resize, event-listener

In my WP website I have a div with current menu item `.side-nav-left` and another below with the other menu items `#sidebar-fixed`.

Then the screen goes below 755, the div below disappears and `.side-nav-left` becomes a button to toggle the div below.

I have placed it before head in theme options.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        checkScreenSize();
    });

    checkScreenSize();

    function checkScreenSize(){
        var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (newWindowWidth < 755) {
        $('#sidebar-fixed').hide();
          $('.side-nav-left').on('click', function(){
          $('#sidebar-fixed').toggle();
            })
        }
        else
        {
        $('#sidebar-fixed').show();
        $('.side-nav-left').off();

        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Div `#sidebar-fixed` gets shown or hidden correctly on screen resizes always.

The problem is the button `.side-nav-left`, which sometimes works sometimes not. For instance, I have an accordian in the page coming from a plugin. If I resize the screen below 755 the button does not work. If I open the accordian and try again my toggle then it works. Then if I click again the accordian it stops working.

Or sometimes I resize the screen below 755 and it works, then  resize again above 755 and below again and it stops working.

I am trying to understand what's the cause when it does not work. Is it because jQuery is not loaded? Is it a conflict with other jQuery on the site? Or what could it be?

Comment: Are you using the custom jquery in your theme and in which file are you calling the jquery file?

Comment: Chances are you're attaching multiple event listeners. If the number is even, it will toggle the element so it gets hidden again. You could give this a try: `$('.side-nav-left').off().on('click' ...` or set a flag to keep track if the listener was attached already.

Comment: @PriyankaModi yes I am using custom jquery in the theme. I have set it on theme options below head

Comment: Try to trace jquery by resizing the screen. Check whether `checkScreenSize` is executed for all the screens or not. If not, then try to reverse track the code to `resize` function. If yes then try to replace `$('.side-nav-left').on('click', function(){` by `$(document).on('click', '.side-nav-left',  function(){` . hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: @Shikkediel that solved the problem, thanks! If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @MominIqbal that didn't change the result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an event listener is attached with each `resize` event below 755 pixels screen size, so there may be cases where more than one exists on the element. If this number happens to be even, the `toggle` functionality will make it revert to its original state.

Most straightforward approach is to remove any listener already present before attaching:

```
$('.side-nav-left').off().on('click', function() {
  $('#sidebar-fixed').toggle();
});
```

You could also add a flag which is slightly more efficient, although practically this will likely only matter for developers resizing their browser:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var listen;

$(window).resize(checkScreenSize);

checkScreenSize();

function checkScreenSize() {

  var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (newWindowWidth < 755) {
    if (!listen) {
      listen = true;
      $('#sidebar-fixed').hide();
      $('.side-nav-left').off().on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar-fixed').toggle();
      });
    }
  }
  else {
    $('#sidebar-fixed').show();
    $('.side-nav-left').off();
    listen = false;
  }
}
});
```